# Database transactions logging in ejb 2.0

Tags: java, design-patterns, oracle11g, transactions, ejb-2.x

I need some help i re-designing a application. I will explain the scenario.
My application is built on ejb 2.0 and oracle.

During transaction(X) at nth step there was a exception then we just serialize the required object in the catch block and start a new transaction(Y) after a specified time period from the nth step. But while reaching to nth step the transaction (X) had performed some db updates/inserts/deletes . But these all get rolled back with the transaction (X). we want to get a log of all those updates and re perform all those with our new serialized object in just one step .
can you suggest some way to do it ??

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in the EJB programming model for recording and playing back a sequence of events.  You will have to build the infrastructure to track this yourself.